# all bundle products in an order (order items list)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been tasked with reverse engineering our product bundles.

We have 2 bundles, one with 3 products and one with 4.

Example:

Bundle Table

```
SKU 1      Bundle 1
SKU 2      Bundle 1
SKU 3      Bundle 1
SKU 4      Bundle 1
SKU 5      Bundle 2
SKU 6      Bundle 2
SKU 7      Bundle 2
SKU 8      Bundle 2
SKU 9      Bundle 2
```

I need to locate each order with corresponding SKUs with all bundle products.

I can do this easily hardcoding but that's not the best way...

```
select 'BUNDLE 1'
from dbo.[Order] o
where exists (select 1 from dl.OrderItem ol where ol.Order_ID = o.Order_ID and ol.SKUVariant = 'SKU1')
and exists   (select 1 from dl.OrderItem ol where ol.Order_ID = o.Order_ID and ol.SKUVariant = 'SKU2')
and exists   (select 1 from dl.OrderItem ol where ol.Order_ID = o.Order_ID and ol.SKUVariant = 'SKU3')
and exists   (select 1 from dl.OrderItem ol where ol.Order_ID = o.Order_ID and ol.SKUVariant = 'SKU4')
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically to make a comparison of the datasets?

Thanks in advance for this one and let me know if there is anymore info you'd like.

Comment: Why is sku 7 duplicated?

Comment: apologies, it is meant to be 8 but i missed it.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Adding DDL for the tables would be a good start. Do you want more than an unnamed column with the value `'BUNDLE 1'` for each applicable order as the result?

Comment: Did you get what's needed here?  Any issues with the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your replies. I couldn't apply any of them as they were hard coded too.

In the end I developed a cursor to provide the text required which dynamically calculated the update statement based upon the original query. The update was then per bundle using the variable from the output of the cursor.

Appreciate cursors aren't great from a performance point of view but i seemed to have exhausted all my options.

Thanks again

Will

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for something like this

```
with
bundles_cte(SKUVariant, BundleNum) as (
    select * from (values ('SKU1', 1), ('SKU2', 1), ('SKU3', 1),
                          ('SKU4', 1), ('SKU5', 2), ('SKU6', 2),
                          ('SKU7', 2), ('SKU8', 2), ('SKU9', 2)),
bundles_sum_cte(BundleNum, ItemCount) as (
    select BundleNum, count(*) from bundles_cte group by BundleNum),
orders_cte(Order_ID, BundleNum, ItemCount) as (
    Select o.Order_ID, bc.BundleNum, count(distinct bc.SKUVariant)
    from dbo.[Order] o 
         join dbo.OrderItem oi on o.Order_id=oi.Order_id
         join bundles_cte bc on oi.SKUVariant=bc.SKUVariant
    group by o.Order_ID, bc.BundleNum)
select o.*
from orders_cte o
where exists(select 1 
             from bundles_sum_cte bsc
             where bsc.BundleNum=o.BundleNum
                   and bsc.ItemCount=o.ItemCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is like this.
and I've thought that your bundle table's name like this 'dbo.BundlesTable'

```
select 'Bundle 1'
from dbo.[order] o
where not exists 
((select SKU 
from dbo.BundlesTable 
where Bundle = 'Bundle 1') 
except
(select SKUVariant 
from dl.OrderItem ol 
where ol.Order_ID = o.Order_ID))
```